# WPF: cancel window from continuing to load from the Loaded event

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to cancel the loading and not show the window if my else statement executes in the loaded event. See the code below.

```
private void OpenTradesLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (OpenTradesQuery.Count() > 0)
    {
        numOfrecords = OpenTradesQuery.Count();
        DataContext = this;

        foreach (var rowObj in OpenTradesQuery)
        {
            row = SourceTable.NewRow();
            SourceTable.Rows.Add(rowObj.TraderID, rowObj.ClientTradedDate, rowObj.ClientTradedTime, rowObj.ClientName, rowObj.CurrencyPair, rowObj.TradedAmount, rowObj.Action, rowObj.ExecutedRate);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Mouse.OverrideCursor = System.Windows.Input.Cursors.Arrow;
        MeBox.Show("You have no open trades.", "", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);

        **//Cancel Loading here and do not show window**
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this property:

```
    public bool ShouldLoad
    {
        get { return OpenTradesQuery.Count() > 0; }
    }
```

And when you want to open, ask if should open:

```
    MyPage mypage = new MyPage();

    if (mypage.ShouldLoad)
    {
        mmypage.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        MeBox.Show("You have no open trades.", "", MessageBoxButton.OK, 
                   MessageBoxImage.Error);
    }
```

With this code, you can check before loading if it really should load.

Answer (score 0):

I just used

```
this.Close();
```

works fine.

Comment: Why not make a public method that returns `true` when `OpenTradesQuery.Count() > 0` and then start loading the form?